# Jasmine spy not being called

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have created an angular service which I am testing without any issue, I then started trying to inject a dependency into the tests when I started having an issue.

I want to make sure that a function in the dependency has been called but it's coming back undefined.

Here's my service:

```
angular.module('enigmaApp.services', [])
    .factory('auth', function($window, $http, SS){
        var auth = {};

        auth.register = function(user){
            return $http.post('/register', user)
            .success(function(data){
                if(data.token){
                    SS.setObj('appToken', data.token);
                }
            });
        };

        return auth;
    });
```

My test:

```
describe('Auth Service Tests', function () {
  var $httpBackend, auth, defer, registerReqHandler, setObjSpy, SS, SSMock, user;

  beforeEach(module('enigmaApp'));

  beforeEach(function () {    
    // Create spies
    setObjSpy = jasmine.createSpy('setObj');

    SSMock = {
      setObj: setObjSpy
    }

    SS = SSMock;

    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('SS', SSMock);
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $injector, $q) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_; 
    defer = $q.defer();
    registerReqHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', '/register').respond(defer.promise);
    auth = $injector.get('auth');
  }));

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  describe('auth.register(user)', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      user = {
        email: 'bwayne@wayneenterprise.com',
        first_name: 'Bruce',
        last_name: 'Wyane',
        password: 'password123'
      };
    });

    it('should call SS.setObj on successful registration', function () {
      $httpBackend.expectPOST('/register').respond({ token: 'fakeToken' });
      auth.register(user);
      expect(SS.setObj).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

When I run the tests I get a failed test that says "Expected spy setObj to have been called." Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here? I thought I set up a mock for SS.setObj and provided it to the module,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is that it seems you aren't actually returning your `auth` object in your factory:

```
angular.module('enigmaApp.services', [])
.factory('auth', function($window, $http, SS){
    var auth = {};

    auth.register = function(user){
        return $http.post('/register', user)
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.token){
                SS.setObj('appToken', data.token);
            }
        });
    };


    // need to return auth here...
    return auth;
});
```

**update**

Move your flush call into your it block

```
it('should call SS.setObj on successful registration', function () {

  $httpBackend
    .expectPOST('/register')
    .respond({ token: 'fakeToken' });

  auth.register(user);
  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect(SS.setObj).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

`afterEach` blocks are for clean up. Jasmine assumes your test is over by that point so your `flush()` call won't have any effect.

Comment: I'm actually passing that, I had deleted some irrelevant code in this post to keep my example concise and that was part of what got deleted. I've added it back into my example.

Comment: It's always dangerous to try and edit stuff you think is irrelevant. All we have to go on is what you give us. Could you make a plunker demonstrating the issue, it would make it much easier to debug.

Comment: Seems you are calling flush in the wrong place. You need to move it into your it block. http://plnkr.co/edit/CArWtpSpVKKEdgTkFpT4?p=preview

Comment: I've never used plunker before so I copied the code from the example you showed me in my last question. http://plnkr.co/edit/5fCTnU28g9D358mGtSi0?p=preview

Comment: See updated answer. I would recommend spending some time using it. It's quite easy and extremely useful for reproducing bugs.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Yeah it was pretty cool I'll have to check it out. Is there any way to do this so I don't need to add the flush in every test though? I was hoping that was what the afterEach would do for me,

Comment: Not really. You need to call it at the correct point depending on your test.